# Yoneda-type lemma for compositions on the hom-functor

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

The Yoneda lemma basically rephrases a rigidity property of natural transformations out of a covariant hom functor: A natural transformation $\psi : \mathsf{Hom}(Z,-)\Rightarrow F$ is determined by the image of the identity $1_Z$ by $\psi _Z$

I noticed a similar rigidity of natural transformations, this time out of the singular chain functor(s) $S_n=\mathbb Z \circ \mathsf{Hom}(\Delta ^n,-)$, where the same statement holds. This rigidity lies at the heart of acyclic models, since it reduces the problem of constructing chain homotopies to constructing just a few homomorphisms.

My question is very simple:

> Is there a characterization, or at least a general sufficient
> condition on the functor $G$ below such that the statement holds?
>
> **Statement.** A natural transformation $\psi : G\circ\mathsf{Hom}(Z,-)\Rightarrow F$ is determined by the image of the identity $1_{GZ}$ by $\psi _Z$

For the sake of completeness, here's the naturality square:
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} G\circ \mathsf{Hom}(Z,Z) @>{\psi _Z}>> FZ\\ @V{G\circ \mathsf{Hom}(Z,f)}VV @VV{F(f)}V\\ G\circ \mathsf{Hom}(Z,B) @>>{\psi _B}> FB \end{CD}$$

Comment: A sufficient condition which is also fulfilled in the case of the singular chain functor is the property of $G$ having a rightadjoint $H$.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "rigidity". In fact, I would rather call it "freeness": the Yoneda lemma says precisely thate $\mathrm{Hom}(Z, -)$ is freely generated by $\mathrm{id}_Z$.

Comment: Small nitpick: What do you mean by the "image of the identity $1_{GZ}$ by $\psi_Z$"? $\psi_Z$ is a morphism of the shape $G(Hom(Z,Z))\rightarrow F(Z)$ in the codomain of $G$ resp. $F$. Instead, one could ask for which functors $G$ such natural transformations are determined by their component at $Z$, which will be the case in the situation in mentioned in my comment before.

Comment: Why are answers given in comments? Please post them as answers so that they can be accepted etc.

Comment: Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two natural transformations of the shape above with the same component at $Z$ and $H$ a right adjoint for the functor $G$. Starting from $\phi$ and $\psi$, use the adjointness to obtain two natural transformations $Hom(Z,\_)\implies H\circ F$, which have the same component at $Z$ and therefore coincide by Yoneda. Finally use the adjointness backwards to conclude that $\psi$ and $\phi$ have to be equal.

Comment: @ZhenLin what do you mean by freely generated? What's the appropriate definition of this term here?

Comment: The functor $F \mapsto F (Z)$ has a left adjoint, whose value at $1$ is $\mathrm{Hom} (Z, -)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP suggested, I post my comments as an answer:

What is meant by the "image of the identity $1_{GZ}$ by $\psi_Z$"? $\psi_Z$ is a morphism of the shape $G(Hom(Z,Z))\rightarrow F(Z)$ in the codomain of G resp. F. Instead, one could ask for which functors G such natural transformations are determined by their component at Z.

In that case, a sufficient condition, which is also fulfilled in the case of the singular chain functor, is the property of $G$ having a rightadjoint :

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two natural transformations of the shape of the question with the same component at Z and H a right adjoint for the functor G. Starting from $\phi$ and $\psi$, use the adjointness to obtain two natural transformations $Hom(Z,\_)\implies H\circ F$, which have the same component at Z and therefore coincide by Yoneda. Finally use the adjointness backwards to conclude that $\psi$ and $\phi$ have to be equal.

Comment: I don't understand the argument: adjointness sends to components of the natural transormations $\phi,\psi$ to arrows $Hom(Z,A)\Rightarrow HF(A)$, but how do I know these arrows form natural transformations? I asked this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435069/is-the-adjoint-of-a-natural-transformation-also-a-natural-transformation).